# Change notification sound from notification service extension

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I want to set a custom notification sound, like the whats app.

I want to modify the notification sound after getting it from the backend, but unfortunately, the `didreceive` notification extension method is not called.

How can I do that?

Comment: What have you tired so far? Please post examples of the code you need help with.

Comment: @Rastalamm can you please explain the procedure of doing this . I have no idea on it

Comment: please share some code samples of what you have written. The file where you are calling and/or expecting the `didreceive`notification to fire/catch would be a good place to start.